# Delete the class after running the animation

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am trying to add a class only while the animation is running and then remove it after running. The animation is infinite.

1. `addClass` seems to be successful but is the event `animationiteration` correct?
2. How to code `removeClass`?

```js
var $box = $('.box');
var isAnimate = false;

$box.on('animationiteration', function() {
  if (isAnimate) {
    return;
  } else {
    $box.addClass('animation');
    isAnimate = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  animation: animation 6s ease 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.6) rotate(-45deg);
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The animation is infinite. So when you have to remove the class?

Comment: And if it ends somewhen, use javascripts [onanimationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event) listener to remove the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't follow CSS animation cycles from Javascript. However you can fake it by using a timer. Since your animation cycle takes 6 seconds, you can use a 6 seconds long timeout to stop the animation around the end of the cycle.

Some additional things, to prevent flickering at the start and the end:

1. Set the initial transformation on the box as well
2. After the timeout add a new class which has the transformation of the last keyframe.

Here's how:

```js
var $box = $('.box');

$box.addClass('animation');
setTimeout(function() {
  $box.addClass('end-state');
  $box.removeClass('animation');
}, 6000);
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
  transform: scale(.3); /*transformation from the first keyframe*/
}

.end-state {
  /*transformation and other properties from the last keyframe*/
  transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
  background: blue;
}

.animation {
  animation: animation 6s ease 0s infinite;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.3);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.6) rotate(-45deg);
    background: red;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to remove `infinite` from the animation property and forget about `onanimationiteration` as that does not seem to be what you want.

```
<style>
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #000;
    }

    .animate {
        animation: animation 6s;
    }

    @keyframes animation {
        0% {
            transform: scale(.3);
        }
        50% {
            transform: scale(.6) rotate(-45deg);
            background: red;
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
            background: blue;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $box = $('.box');
    $box.addClass('animate');
    
    
    $box.on('animationend', function() {
      $box.removeClass('animate');
    });
</script>
```

Without jQuery it would be something like:

```
<style>
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #000;
    }

    .animate {
        animation: animation 6s;
    }

    @keyframes animation {
        0% {
            transform: scale(.3);
        }
        50% {
            transform: scale(.6) rotate(-45deg);
            background: red;
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
            background: blue;
        }
    }
</style>

<div class="box"></div>

<script>
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    box.classList.add('animate');
    
    box.addEventListener('onanimationend', function() {
        box.classList.remove('animate');
    });
</script>
```

You can check out more about this on mdn.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnimationEvent